# Comparing Common Values between two files of different length (Linux)

Tags: awk, text-processing

I've compared two files that are of different lengths, for which I first found unique IDs that ARE present in file 1 but not in file 2.

However, now I want to find common unique values between the files, I've seen multiple times the use of the comm command, however, these files are not of the same length.

### Example

*file 1*:

```
2 
4 
6 
8 
10
```

*file 2:*

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

*Desired Output:*

```
2 
4 
6 
8
```

For Finding Unique Differences I used the following command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !($0 in a)' file1.sorted file2.sorted > diff_values.txt
```

For Finding Common Values I have tried using the following command but am not entirely sure if this is the correct approach or if there exist any alternatives:

```
comm -12 file1.sorted file2.sorted > comm_values.txt
```

Comment: The `++` in `a[$0]++` is doing nothing but taking up CPU cycles and possibly memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many alternatives to using `comm`, just as there are many alternatives to doing anything in Unix, but `comm` is the tool designed to do what you're asking for.

Common lines:

```
$ comm -12 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
2
4
6
8
```

Different lines:

```
$ comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
        1
10
        3
        5
        7
        9
```

Lines only in the first file:

```
$ comm -23 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
10
```

Lines only in  the second file:

```
$ comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
1
3
5
7
9
```

If you want alternatives though, here's some of the many alternative scripts you could consider and adapt to whatever you want to do:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; c[$0]; next} {b[$0]; c[$0]} END{for (i in c) if ((i in a) && (i in b)) print i}' file1 file2
2
4
6
8

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; c[$0]; next} {b[$0]; c[$0]} END{for (i in c) if (!((i in a) && (i in b))) print i}' file1 file2
1
3
5
7
9
10

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; c[$0]; next} {b[$0]; c[$0]} END{for (i in c) if ((i in a) && !(i in b)) print i}' file1 file2
10

$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; c[$0]; next} {b[$0]; c[$0]} END{for (i in c) if (!(i in a) && (i in b)) print i}' file1 file2
1
3
5
7
9
```

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer @Ed definitely works and covers what I need